# My react component is not displaying using routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a personal project I'm working on and I have run into a bit of a problem. I have two simple code snippets one for the component and one for handling the route.

````
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function setPath {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/sect/guest" element={<MobileCardsGuest />} />
    <Routes/>
  )
} ```
````

the setPath component is called in App.js

component to be displayed

```
import React from "react";
import eventIcon from "../../assets/img/red-carpet.png";
import mealIcon from "../../assets/img/hamburger.png";
import accIcon from "../../assets/img/accomodation.png";
import "../../assets/css/mobilecards.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

function MobileCardsGuest() {
  const notify = ()=>{
    return toast.info("Coming Soon")
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="mobile-card">
      <p className="text-center mob-title">
        <b style={{ color: "var(--pieme-color)" }}>You are Welcome</b>
      </p>
      <p className="text-center mob-body">Please choose what you would like</p>
      <div class="card bg-light m-card">
     
        <p></p>
          <img src={mealIcon} className="iconimg" alt="Meal Icon"/>
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <p class="card-text">Meal</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card bg-light m-card">
        <p></p>
          <img src={accIcon} className="iconimg" alt="Acc Icon" />
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <p class="card-text">Accomodation</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
     </div>

      <div class="card bg-light m-card" onClick={notify}>
        <p></p>
        <img src={eventIcon} className="iconimg" alt="Event Icon"/>
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <p class="card-text">Event</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MobileCardsGuest;
```

the other component

```
import useNavigate from "react-router-dom"
const navigate= useNavigate();
function Navbar{
  return (
      <button onClick={() => {navigate("/sect/guest")>
          Guest
      </button>
  )
}
```

When I run the above and go to the path"/sect/guest"` it doesn't display the component.

Comment: Did you use browser router at entry point?

Comment: Where are you rendering any routes to render routed content? Where is `setPath ` called? Please edit the post to include a more complete and cohesive [mcve] so we better context what is being rendered and where.

Comment: BTW it appears your code is incomplete or has some issues. There is no opening `Link` component tag. Please fix the code to at least be syntactically correct.

Comment: i use useNavigate to navigate to that route.  navigate = useNavigate;  navigate("/sect/guest");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using react 18 or latest react-router-dom then your routes structure would be like :

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
  </Routes>
<Router>
```

Here BrowserRouter and switch will not beused in newer version applications.

Comment: Just FYI, `react@18` has nothing to do with `react-router-dom`. Mentioning it isn't relevant here. Also, the high-level routers like `BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, etc... ***should*** still be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import BrowserRouter as well.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MobileCardsGuest from './path/MobileCardsGuest';

const SetPath = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/sect/guest' element={<MobileCardsGuest />} />
      </Routes>
      ... ...
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default SetPath;
```